# setInterval() not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript. I run my code which calculates time a user have been alive based on the input. If you would like to see the code run, its available on my class test server at [here](http://jmkll.net/~bcastro13/bcastro13_lab03.html).

The problem with my code is that setInterval() is not working properly. From my understanding, my html page should be updated every 1000ms(1s) with the newest time, but instead it does nothing, it does not update.

I've used setInterval() before on a similar project that displayed the number of seconds since the Epoch and it worked fine. It updated the seconds as it should. Maybe theres something else in my code not allowing it to work? I've run my code through jslint and jshint and cannot find the mistake I'm making.

Thanks in advance!

```
function getUserBirthday(myEpoch) {
    "use strict";
    var unixEpoch = new Date() / 1000.0;
    var secondSince = unixEpoch - myEpoch;
    var leftOrAlive = "";
    if (secondSince < 0) {
        leftOrAlive = ": Seconds Left";
        secondSince = secondSince * -1;
    } else {
        leftOrAlive = ": Seconds Alive";
    }
    document.getElementById("secondsAlive").innerHTML = secondSince + leftOrAlive;
    var years = secondSince / 31556926;
    secondSince = secondSince % 31556926;
    var months = secondSince / 2629743;
    secondSince = secondSince % 2629743;
    var days = secondSince / 86400;
    secondSince = secondSince % 86400;
    var hours = secondSince / 3600;
    secondSince = secondSince % 3600;
    var minutes = secondSince / 60;
    secondSince = secondSince % 60;
    var seconds = secondSince;
    //Convert Variables To String
    years = years.toString();
    months = months.toString();
    days = days.toString();
    hours = hours.toString();
    minutes = minutes.toString();
    seconds = seconds.toString();
    //Remove Trailing Decimal Places
    var yearStr = years.slice(0, (years.indexOf(".")));
    var monthStr = months.slice(0, (months.indexOf(".")));
    var dayStr = days.slice(0, (days.indexOf(".")));
    var hourStr = hours.slice(0, (hours.indexOf(".")));
    var minuteStr = minutes.slice(0, (minutes.indexOf(".")));
    var secondStr = seconds.slice(0, (seconds.indexOf(".")));
    //Show Results
    document.getElementById("years").innerHTML = yearStr + ": Years";
    document.getElementById("months").innerHTML = monthStr + ": Months";
    document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = dayStr + ": Days";
    document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hourStr + ": Hours";
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minuteStr + ": Minutes";
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = secondStr + ": Second
}

function updateTimeSinceEpoch() {
    "use strict";
    var strDate = prompt("Enter your birthday: ex. November 12, 1996 00:00:00");
    document.getElementById("birthday").innerHTML = strDate;
    var myDate = new Date(strDate); // Your timezone!
    var myEpoch = myDate.getTime() / 1000.0;
    var runFunction = getUserBirthday(myEpoch);
    setInterval(runFunction, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You have got a syntax-error with the last line of getUserBirthday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using:

```
var runFunction = getUserBirthday(myEpoch);
setInterval(runFunction, 1000);
```

the `runFunction` variable is `undefined`, because `getUserBirthday()` method doesn't return anything. So with this structure your function will be executed only once:

```js
function getUserBirthday(message) {
  console.log(message);
}

var runFunction = getUserBirthday("Hello");
setInterval(runFunction, 1000);
```

Try to use the following structure, it should do the trick:

```js
function getUserBirthday(message) {
  console.log(message);
}

setInterval(function() {
  getUserBirthday('Hello');
}, 1000);
```